# Select subsets from a list based on a criterion?

Tags: summation, filtering, sequence

Assume we have a set of numbers, for instance $A=\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and we are looking for the sums of reciprocals such that they are less than one. I mean I am looking for all $S_B$'s
$$
S_B=\sum_{i\in B}\frac1i<1,
$$
where $B\subset A$. How can I write such code in "**Mathematica**"?

I wrote the following code but it does not work properly

```
Clear[A]
A = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Table[If[SubsetQ[A,B] == True&& Sum[1/i, {i, B}]<1,Sum[1/i, {i, B}], Nothing], {B,A}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
A = Subsets@Range[2., 10.];
Select[{#, Sum[i^-1, {i, #}]} & /@ A, #[[2]] < 1 &]
```

> {{{},0},{{2.},0.5},{{3.},0.333333},{{4.},0.25},<<267>>,{{4.,5.,7.,8.,9.,10.},0.928968},{{4.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.},0.895635},{{5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.},0.845635}}

Comment: thanks, what if we need only the second values, {0,0.5,0.3333,0.25,...}?

Comment: @asad If you only want the sums and don't care about the subsets that correspond to them, then just use `Select[Sum[i^-1, {i, #}] & /@ A, # < 1 &]`.

Comment: The sum can also be written as `Total[1/#]&` for improved readability & speed

Answer (score 4):

```
selected = Select[# < 1 &] @ Total[Subsets[1. /Range[2, 10]], {2}];

selected // Short
```

> {0., 0.5, 0.333333, 0.25, 0.2, << 265 >>, 0.952778, 0.928968, 0.895635, 0.845635}

```
Length @ selected
```

> 274